# Multipart request rejected because no bounday were found while boundary is already sent

Tags: spring-boot, http-headers, mulesoft

I went through the other similar questions but couldn't find any solution. We have a backend service running by Spring Boot and has been working for a while now. But there is a new user of this service recently and they are using MuleSoft to send their request. But all attempts to send a file to our service fails with this error:

```
Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found"
```

The only difference we could find between a request from MuleSoft and say a `curl` command is that MuleSoft always sends the request with boundary value wrapped with double quotes

Mule request:

```
<Header name="Content-Type">multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8; boundary="--------------------------669816398596264398718285"</Header>
```

Versus Postman/curl request:

```
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multiplexing
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x7fd656810a00)
> POST /api/upload HTTP/2
> Host: myhost
> user-agent: curl/7.79.1
> accept: */*
> content-length: 97255
> content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------111fd08cb4fafe1c
> 
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/2 200 
< date: Mon, 19 Dec 2022 04:56:25 GMT
< content-length: 0
```

Our controller in Spring is very simple:

```
@RestController
class MyController {

    @PostMapping("/upload", consumes = [MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE])
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    fun uploadDocument(@RequestPart("file") file: MultipartFile) {
        logger.info { "ContentType: ${file.contentType}" }
        logger.info { "Name: ${file.name}" }
        logger.info { "Byte: ${String(file.bytes)}" }
    }
}
```

The following `curl` command works fine:

```
curl -v -X POST -F file=@/Users/myhomefolder/Documents/some-file.jpg https://host-name/api/upload
```

But this script from MuleSoft doesn't (Sorry I'm not familiar with Mule, I got this code from their team):

```
import dw::module::Multipart 
output multipart/form-data boundary = "---WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"
---
{
               parts : {
                    file : {
                        headers : {
                            "Content-Disposition" : {
                                "name": "file",
                                "filename": payload.name
                             },
                            "Content-Type" : "multipart/form-data"            
                        },
                        content : payload.byteArray
                    }
               }

}
```

Is there any configuration in Spring that accepts double quotes for `boundary`? Is there anything missing in our backend configuration that should be added to support different HTTP client?

Comment: Can you please both working and non working curl requests

Comment: Updated the post. As I mentioned I'm not familiar with MuleSoft.

Comment: MuleSoft the company name. Mule 4 is the product that your client is using.

Comment: Please share the entire HTTP  requests from both the Mule client and Postman. Quotes in the header are unlikely to be the issue since there  are many examples of using them in multi part requests, even in the RFC. Also the DataWeave snippet from Mule 4 shows a fixed boundary that doesn't match the header shared. Why is that in XML anyway? Please share the raw requests.